# Laravel passport login system, how to login the user and get access_token and refresh token?

Tags: php, laravel, ionic-framework, laravel-passport

I am using laravel `5.6` and passport is installed and working. I wanted to login the user by sending the post request from ionic 3 application. I wanted to know how to make the login route.

I already made create account route which is working and after user creates account it returns the `access_token` and `refresh_token`. But how to implement this for the login route?

I found we can do by using following code by sending post request to the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token` route but... is it safe to save `client_id` and `client_secret` in the ionic app itself?

What are the best practices to login the user using laravel passport by sending post request from ionic 3 app (or any other front end framework)?

```json
{
    "grant_type" : "password",
    "client_id" : "2",
    "client_secret" : "HqLqRCRzNN2dwLWM1JhvCoNrbndwNSTGz515hSrswT",
    "username" : "test@test.com",
    "password" : "123456"  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 2020's Update

There's now an alternative to Passport to authenticate SPAs and mobile apps (also maintained by the Laravel): [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/sanctum).

Note: This library requires Laravel v6.9+.

---

---

### Original answer

Exposing client-credentials is always risky because you don't have full control of the client apps.

If you don't want to store that kind of data in the client-side you could make a little proxy to receive username/password and then complete the call adding the passport client details.

Citing [this](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/api-authentication-with-passport) answer made by @adiachenko:

> #### routes/api.php
>
> ```php
> Route::post('auth/token', 'Api\Auth\DefaultController@authenticate');
> Route::post('auth/refresh', 'Api\Auth\DefaultController@refreshToken');
> ```
>
> #### app/Http/Controllers/Api/Auth/DefaultController.php
>
> ```php
> <?php
>
> namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;
>
> use Illuminate\Http\Request;
> use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
>
> class DefaultController extends Controller
> {
>     /**
>      * @var object
>      */
>     private $client;
>
>     /**
>      * DefaultController constructor.
>      */
>     public function __construct()
>     {
>         $this->client = DB::table('oauth_clients')->where('id', 2)->first();
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @param Request $request
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     protected function authenticate(Request $request)
>     {
>         $request->request->add([
>             'username' => $request->username,
>             'password' => $request->password,
>             'grant_type' => 'password',
>             'client_id' => $this->client->id,
>             'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
>             'scope' => '*'
>         ]);
>
>         $proxy = Request::create(
>             'oauth/token',
>             'POST'
>         );
>
>         return Route::dispatch($proxy);
>     }
>
>     /**
>      * @param Request $request
>      * @return mixed
>      */
>     protected function refreshToken(Request $request)
>     {
>         $request->request->add([
>             'grant_type' => 'refresh_token',
>             'refresh_token' => $request->refresh_token,
>             'client_id' => $this->client->id,
>             'client_secret' => $this->client->secret,
>         ]);
>
>         $proxy = Request::create(
>             '/oauth/token',
>             'POST'
>         );
>
>         return Route::dispatch($proxy);
>     }
> }
> ```

As you can see, you'll need to make a POST call to `/auth/token` sending user credentials:

```php
{ 
   "username" : "some@email.com",
   "password" : "some-awesome-password"
}
```

then the `authenticate` method will complete the passport-client details to continue with the flow.